# How to detect if a page scrolled in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, scrolling

Please suggest a way to check if a user scrolled down.

as of now I have only the below way but only provide scroll count instead of the direction.

```
connectedCallback() {
    this.count = 0;
    window.addEventListener('scroll', () => console.log(`scrolled ${this.count++} times`));
}
```

I need to display a button which will scroll up to the top of the page but it needs to be rendered only if a user scrolled down and if user is already at the top or reached back to the top of the page then this button should not be rendered, I have created this button and it is working as expected the only problem is when to render and when not.

Comment: did you try using onscroll like onscroll={handleNotification} then in the function you can print  console.log('Current value of the input: ' + evt.target.scrollTop); which will be 0 at the top

Comment: And also in function  handleNotification(evt) {
        console.log('Current value of the input: ' + evt.target.scrollTop);

    
   
}

Comment: Thank you for your response, but where should I put onscroll, please post this as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Presuming the event is firing, you should be able to see if you're at the top via:

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', event => console.log(`scrolled to ${event.target.scrollTop}`));
```

Comment: Thank you so much for responding I added the above line in the connected callback but didn't get any console log upon scrolling up and down on the page.

Comment: @gs650x Yeah, I wasn't entirely sure that the event was firing to begin with, but that's how'd you access it. I suggest using a full-screen wrapper element and check for scrolling on that.

Comment: could please provide any documentation related to full-screen wrapper element, I never used it before

Comment: @gs650x Here's a [playground](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/qKcmUdV9o/1/edit) for you.

Comment: Thank you so much again for the playground now everything is working as expected but the top button has stopped working I have updated the code on playground with the button, request you to please take a look and suggest.

Comment: Hi @sfdcfox I am getting 'event.target.scrollTop' undefined. Can you please help me

Comment: Also, I try the onscroll on HTML part but not getting event in JS

Comment: @Rijwandeltax if you could share your code, if be happy to look at it with you.

Comment: connectedCallback(){
        window.addEventListener('scroll', event => console.log(event));
 }

    handleScroll(evt) {
        console.log('scrollTop: ' + evt.target.scrollTop);
    }

/////////////html part///////////
<template>
 <div onscroll={handleScroll} class="ooo">
</div>
</template>

Comment: @sfdcfox Can you please help me in this issue

Answer (score 2):

Put onscroll on an element like

```
 <div class="app slds-p-around_x-large" onscroll={handleNotification}>
```

then in js

```
handleNotification(evt) 
{ console.log('Current value of the input: ' + evt.target.scrollTop); }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for responding this is exactly what I am looking for it works as expected in playground but in real time I wrapped my whole code in a div tag with on scroll function but i am not getting any any console log when I scroll down, could you please suggest?

Comment: can you share your code

Comment: I solved the problem by updating the CSS

Comment: Hi @gs650x, Can you please show me the code snippets